# Open CMD terminal Automatic on boot up

Tags: raspbian

How do I get the CMD terminal to open up on its own when I start the raspberry pi up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Figured it out. What you do is sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LDXE-pi/autostart, then add @lxterminal and it will autostart the cmd terminal on bootup, which will then run my shell script and go to the website

Answer (score 1):

To start the Raspberry Pi into the command line then just execute

```
rpi ~$ sudo raspi-config
```

and select `3 Boot Options` -> `B1 Desktop / CLI` -> `B1 Console` or `B2 Console Autologin`, just what you want. On the next boot you will have a text console instead of the graphical user interface.

Comment: I've tried this but the problem is, I need the cmd terminal to open up in the desktop GUI. I need this because I'm trying to run a shell script that opens up the internet, and goes straight to a website on boot up. If I open the terminal it runs everything and goes straight to the website, I just need the cmd terminal to open on boot up, but it has to be in the desktop GUI so it can open chromium

Comment: @ParkerStearns You should have mentioned this important information in your question.